How to compare multiple columns and update a new column with boolean logic in kdb/q?
Compare the numbers in 3 columns and then create a new column based on the result of the boolean check.
id    col1     col2       col3         col4                    
---------------------------------------------

update checkCol:$[(exec col1 from table)~(exec col2 from table1)~(exec col3 from table2);1;0] from table
I know the code above won't work but it gives a good idea of what I want to achieve. Is there a better way to approach this other than just a standard update statement?
q)tb:([] id:1 2 3 4; num1: 20 22 24 26; num2: 21 22 24 27; num3: 20 22 24 28)
q)tb
id num1 num2 num3
-----------------
1  20   21   20  
2  22   22   22  
3  24   24   24  
4  26   27   28  
q)n1:exec num1 from tb
q)n2:exec num2 from tb
q)n3:exec num3 from tb
q){$[y~x;1;0]}'[n1;n2]
0 1 1 0

Adding the 3rd col causes issues

q)update checkCol:1={count distinct x}each flip (num1;num2;num3) from tb
id num1 num2 num3 checkCol
--------------------------
1  20   21   20   0
2  22   22   22   1
3  24   24   24   1
4  26   27   28   0

If you just want booleans output of the table:
q)1={count distinct x}each flip tb`num1`num2`num3
0110b


q)flip (num1;num2;num3)
'num3
[0]  flip (num1;num2;num3)
^
q)
when i run it by itself is throws an error
q)1={count distinct x}each flip (num1;num2;num3)
'num3
[0]  1={count distinct x}each flip (num1;num2;num3)
^
q)
But when i run it all together it works

Yes it works but when i just run the code without the update logic it doesn't work

Alternative example added if you don't want qsql

Are you able to explain how the first example is working despite not working when run separately as it is confusing to breakdown and understand

In qsql update select exec delete you can refer to columns by name as if they are variables. Outside of qsql you must extract them from the table. https://code.kx.com/q/basics/qsql/#names-in-subphrases

You can also use the prior iterator: https://code.kx.com/q/ref/prior/ to compare successive items of a list:
q)update checkCol:all 1_(=)prior(num1;num2;num3)from tb
id num1 num2 num3 checkCol
--------------------------
1  20   21   20   0
2  22   22   22   1
3  24   24   24   1
4  26   27   28   0

